# How can we decrease the training time of neural networks without increasing memory?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, training-data

I want to train rnn model(gru+lstm) My training model has 500000 English text and I want to train and evaluate the model with that data. As I check the time of training for one epoch with batch size of 20 is really high(6 hour)

Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #

===============================================================

input_4 (InputLayer)        [(None, 149, 1)]          0

gru_6 (GRU)                 (None, 169)               87204

dense_6 (Dense)             (None, 128)               21760

repeat_vector_3 (RepeatVector)  (None, 169, 128)         0

gru_7 (GRU)                 (None, 169, 128)          99072

time_distributed_3 (TimeDistributed)  (None, 169, 165627)      21365883

===============================================================

Total params: 21,573,919

Trainable params: 21,573,919

Non-trainable params: 0

---

this is a summary of the neural network layers.
I want to know if we have any approach for decreasing training time or not (without increasing memory or increasing batch size).

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the use of `mixed precision`, which can be used for both [`TensorFlow/Keras`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision#gpu_performance_tips) as well as [`PyTorch`](https://pytorch.org/blog/what-every-user-should-know-about-mixed-precision-training-in-pytorch/). By reducing the precision of your model, it requires less memory. For example, a model which only uses `float16` (16-bits) instead of `float32` (32-bits) requires half the memory, which is why you can usually double your `batch size` and thereby speeding up your training significantly.

However, please bear in mind that using the wrong dtypes may not lead to any performance improvement - e.g. using `bfloat16` on `CPU`s without `AMX` (Advanced Matrix Extensions) will not speed up your training and actually make your training slower! Therefore, you should thoroughly read up on the topic and use the provided links as a starting point.

Comment: Since my model ends in softmax, this solution couldn't work for me and I have to use `float32` for quality. Nevertheless, I appreciate your response. If you have any alternative suggestions, I would be delighted to hear them.

Comment: Yes, softmax should be `float32`, as it is mentioned in the TensorFlow documentation I shared. The point of mixed precision is not to lower the precision for all model layers but for those where a lower precision has no negative impact. I personally do not know of any other approach that achieves what you're looking for. If you find something else, let me know!